# Backbone fetch collection lifecycle, set property from response

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Question:

What is the lifecycle of the standard fetch method for a collection in Backbone? i.e. what events/methods are fired and in what order?

Context:

The JSON response I receive from the server for my collection has an array of models and a property:

```
{
    results: [model1, model2],
    aProperty: "example"
}
```

I would like to read this property from the JSON response and set it as a property on the Collection. I am currently overriding the parse function:

```
parse: function(response, options) {
    this.aProperty = response.aProperty;
    return response.results;
}
```

This feels like the wrong place to set properties in the collection - the parse function has a specific job and happens before the model array has been verified.

I have also tried:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.on('sync', function(collection, resp) {
        collection.aProperty = resp.aProperty;
    });
}
```

However, 'sync' is called after the success callback for a fetch (I need to set the properties as part of fetch, before the success callback).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code some, I think what you want to do is capture it on the `request` event. It is triggered on the model in `Backbone.sync`:

```
model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);
```

Here you can override the callback sent as part of the request, wrapping it with the change you want to make. I didn't test this, but maybe this can give you an idea:

```
this.on('request', function(model, xhr, options) {
   var success;
   success = options.success;
   options.success = function(resp) {
        model.aProperty = resp.aProperty;
        success();
   }
});
```

Checkout out the [annotated backbone source documentation](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html). In particular the bit on [Backbone.sync](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-134) will help.